# separate legend geom_smooth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a plot very similar to this one:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x = wt,y =  mpg, colour = factor(cyl)))  + 
  geom_line() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, lty = 2)
```

However, I specifically want a different entry in the legend for the dashed lines (linear trend) and the solid lines (data). This seems very trivial but for some reason I haven't been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to show 6 different levels in one legend that combines linetypes and colors, then one solution would be to make new data frame that contains original `mpg` values and predicted values by linear model.

Make new data frame `mtcars2` where `mgp` is replaced with predicted values.

```
library(plyr)
mtcars2<-ddply(mtcars,.(cyl),mutate,mpg=predict(lm(mpg~wt)))
```

Add new column to `mtcars` and new data frame to show real and predicted data

```
mtcars$type<-"real"
mtcars2$type<-"pred"
```

Combine both data frames.

```
mtcars.new<-rbind(mtcars,mtcars2)
```

Now plot data using combined data frame and for `color=` and `lty=` use interaction between `cyl` and `type`. With `scale_color_manual()` and `scale_linetype_manual()` change values of colors and linetypes.

```
ggplot(mtcars.new,aes(x=wt,y=mpg,color=interaction(type,factor(cyl)),
              lty=interaction(type,factor(cyl))))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_manual("Legend",values=c("red","red",
                            "green","green","blue","blue"))+
  scale_linetype_manual("Legend",values=c(2,1,2,1,2,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was wondering though if it is possible to get the entries mixed in with the colors of the data. As in: 6 entries, red solid: 4, red dashed: 4 (linear trend), green solid: 6, green dashed: 6 (linear trend), blue solid: 8, blue dashed: 8 (linear trend)?

Comment: @SachaEpskamp Updated my answer to have legend with 6 levels